# Sorting a list while keeping a few elements always at the top

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

We have a `List<Country>` which holds the list of countries in alphabetical order sorted by the `countryName`.

```
 class Country {
   int id;
   String countryCode;
   String countryName;
 }
```

`Country` is an entity object and we don't have access to the source (it's in a jar file that is shared by many applications).

Now I want to modify the list in such a way that country names 'United States of America' and 'United Kingdom' comes first and the rest of the list is in the same alphabetical order.

What is the most efficient way to do this ?

Comment: It will help to show how the list is currently being sorted.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: @Sinto, if you still read this: undelete your post. I very much liked your answer and was in the process of double checking it.

Answer (score 10):

Create your own [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) in combination with [`Collections.Sort(collection, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). The way this differs from a normal `Comparator` is that you have to explicitly give preference to the entries that you always want on top.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        List<Country> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Country("Belgium"));
        list.add(new Country("United Kingdom"));
        list.add(new Country("Legoland"));
        list.add(new Country("Bahrain"));
        list.add(new Country("United States of America"));
        list.add(new Country("Mexico"));
        list.add(new Country("Finland"));


        Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());

        for(Country c : list){
            System.out.println(c.countryName);
        }
    }
}

class Country {
    public Country(String name){
        countryName = name;
    }

    int id;
    String countryCode;
    String countryName;

}

class MyComparator implements Comparator<Country> {
    private static List<String> important = Arrays.asList("United Kingdom", "United States of America");

    @Override
    public int compare(Country arg0, Country arg1) {
        if(important.contains(arg0.countryName)) { return -1; }
        if(important.contains(arg1.countryName)) { return 1; }
        return arg0.countryName.compareTo(arg1.countryName);
    }
}
```

Output:

> United States of America
>   United Kingdom
>   Bahrain
>   Belgium
>   Finland
>   Legoland
>   Mexico

I misread your question at first (or it was added as a ninja edit) so here's the updated version.

Comment: The order of "United Kingdom" and "United States" is non-deterministic with that solution. An alternative is to remove the important countries from the list, sort it and then join the list with the important countries and the sorted one.

Answer (score 0):

Implement that rule in a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You can get your list sorted with [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 0):

Something a bit terser:

```
var result = countries
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.countryName == "United States of America")
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.countryName == "United Kingdom")
    .ThenBy(item => item.countryName );
```