# Implementing a Comparator with a specific condition

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I need to implement Comparator to sort `Employee` objects based on a specific condition.

```
 class Employee
 {
      int employeeId;
      String employeeName;

 }
```

So I already have a sorted list of  List in my hand and I modify the sort order as follows

1. Maintain the sort order
2. If employeeName is 'Rock Hudson' in the Employee object, add it to the top of the list.

**>Input:**

> 1 Alan Border
>
> 2 Betty Edwards
>
> 3 Rock Hudson
>
> 4 Quentin Tarantino
>
> 5 Woody Allen

**>Output**:

> 3 Rock Hudson
>
> 1 Alan Border
>
> 2 Betty Edwards
>
> 4 Quentin Tarantino
>
> 5 Woody Allen

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing and Adding java elements in java.util.List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011662/removing-and-adding-java-elements-in-java-util-list)

Comment: So, what is stopping you from implementing the `Comparator` that you described?  Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: yup. why not implement your own comparator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
public static class Employee {
  // a constructor
  public Employee(int id, String name) {
    this.employeeId = id;
    this.employeeName = name;
  }

  // should be private and use getters and setters.
  int employeeId;
  String employeeName;

  // A special Comparator
  public static Comparator<Employee> rockHudsonComparator = new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee a, Employee b) {
      if (a.employeeName.equals("Rock Hudson")) {
        if (b.employeeName.equals("Rock Hudson")) {
          return 0;
        }
        return -1;
      } else if (b.employeeName.equals("Rock Hudson")) {
        return 1;
      }
      return a.employeeName
          .compareTo(b.employeeName);
    }
  };

  public String toString() {
    return "" + employeeId + " " + employeeName;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  java.util.List<Employee> al = new java.util.ArrayList<Employee>();
  al.add(new Employee(1, "Alan Border"));
  al.add(new Employee(2, "Betty Edwards"));
  al.add(new Employee(3, "Rock Hudson"));
  al.add(new Employee(4, "Quentin Tarantino"));
  al.add(new Employee(5, "Woody Allen"));
  al.add(new Employee(6, "Rock Hudson")); // check the sort is stable.
  System.out.println("Before sort");
  System.out.println(al);
  java.util.Collections.sort(al,
      Employee.rockHudsonComparator);
  System.out.println("After sort");
  System.out.println(al);
}
```

Which outputs

```
[1 Alan Border, 2 Betty Edwards, 3 Rock Hudson, 4 Quentin Tarantino, 5 Woody Allen, 6 Rock Hudson]
[3 Rock Hudson, 6 Rock Hudson, 1 Alan Border, 2 Betty Edwards, 4 Quentin Tarantino, 5 Woody Allen]
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I am new to this.. how about if I have more than one preferred elements..for example if I want to move both Rock Hudson AND Woody Allen to the top ?

Comment: You shouldn't make them equal... because then it will appear random if you have 3 of each (as an example). But you could add an `||` and see for yourself with something `if (a.employeeName.equals("Rock Hudson") || a.employeeName.equals("Woody Allen")) {`

Comment: Did you read what I said? No employee has two names simultaneously so it can't be an `and`.

Comment: Don't use an `||`.  Be more flexible.  Give the `Comparator` a field of type `Set<String>` and use `contains`.  And don't forget to be determinate about the order in which the "special" people appear.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a special condition, tested in each direction, for that case:

```
Comparator<Employee> c = new Comparator<Employee>() {
    public int compare(Employee a, Employer b) {
        if (a.getName().equals("Rock Hudson"))
             return -1;
        if (b.getName().equals("Rock Hudson"))
             return 1;
        return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidWallace I did not. I keyed it in on my iphone while driving. Where is the error (it looks OK to me)? btw, I consciously decided the edge case of there being *two* Rock Hudsons was an irrelevancy

Comment: It looks like you found the main error already and fixed it.  There's also the small matter of not obeying the general contract of `Comparator` (see my comment on someone else's answer); but at least this will work.  By the way, my family (but not me) are currently on holiday in Melbourne.  Do you think you could please refrain from answering SO questions while driving, at least until they return?  :-)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch not any more... Muhahaha. But surely it was a typo.

Comment: @DavidWallace there's no danger of collision: I was on the "freeway" at peak hour :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyEmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    private final String alwaysTopEmployee;

    public MyEmployeeComparator(final String alwaysTopEmployee) {
        this.alwaysTopEmployee = alwaysTopEmployee;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        if (o2.getName().equals(alwaysTopEmployee) && o1.getName().equals(alwaysTopEmployee))
            return 0;
        if (o1.getName().equals(alwaysTopEmployee))
            return -1;
        if (o2.getName().equals(alwaysTopEmployee))
            return 1;

        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}
```

and call:

```
Collections.sort(stuff, new MyEmployeeComparator("Rock Hudson"));
```